# Two Oracle ORDS on one web server accessing one database

Tags: oracle, web-server

```
Oracle ORDS 3.0
Oracle 12c database
Red Hat Linux 6.8
Tomcat 8.0.22
```

Can two ORDS be deployed to one web server (Tomcat) and access the same database?
If so, how is this accomplished?

That is, I would be deploying to Tomcat an ords1.war file and an ords2.war file that both connect to the same Oracle database.

Better yet, I need two URLs that point to two different applications running on the same database.  Perhaps another ORDS is not needed.

The context root (normally just 'ords') has to be different for each application.
For example, ords1 and ords2.  Hence, the thought that there needs to be a ords1.war and ords2.war file deployed.

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: I have a request to setup another URL to access the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done.

Make a copy of the existing `ords.war` (call it, say, `ords2.war`) and just follow the same process that you would when creating your initial ORDS .war file. 
Just be sure to use different configuration directories for each ORDS .war file in order to avoid possible collisions.

You name the two ORDS .war file differently in order to change the 'root'.  For example:

```
https://mywebsite.com/ords/...
https://mywebsite.com/ords2/...
```

has the 'root' of `ords` and `ords2`, respectively

Comment: Each ORDS will share a db repo, so upgrade one ORDS, and you'll have to prob upgrade the other

Comment: @thatjeffsmith - thanks for the note.  Not a big problem in my case.  I enjoy your blog btw.

Comment: @thatjeffsmith - can both ORDS share the same cache folder (as defined in the defaults,xml file within each ORDS's conf folder)?  Is there anything else that needs to be defined to avoid collisions?

Comment: they could share that folder - but why do you need 2 ords for the same db? seems like a lot of overhead just to get a different URL

Comment: Thanks Jeff.  Customer requested specific URL that does not contain /ords in the URL string.  Other apps use /ords in the URL.

Comment: why not just setup url rewrites? much simpler than maintaining 2 ords

Comment: @thatjeffsmith - please point me to a tutorial on that and I'll take a look.

Comment: that's an apache/tomcat thing, not an ords thing

Comment: @thatjeffsmith - let me add (for clarification) that only one version of the ORDS software is installed in one folder.  But two separate .war files -- ords1.war and ords2.war -- are being created and deployed using separate conf directories but pointing to the same database.  This may be clear already from the accepted answer but I wanted to be sure..